# flash object not embedding correctly in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I donwloaded this small sample for jquery http://plugins.jquery.com/project/WebcamQRCode it is a plugin for a webpage and it displays a flash player to capture a qr code through a webcam. It shows the flash player in firefox and chrome, but it doesn't show it in IE. I do have the flash player in IE because i tried the project in this webpage [http://blog.jactionscripters.com/2009/05/23/introduction-of-qr-code-reader-library](http://blog.jactionscripters.com/2009/05/23/introduction-of-qr-code-reader-library/)/  and it does display the qr code.

A person told me to check if it was embeded using swfobject and I checked the .js file of the project and it is embedding it as an swfobject, could anybody help me determine what the problem might be?

this is part of the code in the jqery.webcamqrcode.js

```
  $.WebcamQRCode.start = function( $this ){
        var _flash = $('<object></object>');
        var _messageNoFlash = $('<p></p>');
        var __options = $this.data( 'webcam_qrcode_options' );

        // Set message if no flash
        _messageNoFlash.text( __options.messageNoFlash );

        // Set flash object information
        _flash.attr( 'type', "application/x-shockwave-flash" );
        _flash.attr( 'data', __options.path + "swf/webcamqrcode.swf?ID=" + $this.attr( '_webcam_qrcode_id' ) );
        _flash.attr( 'width', "100%" );
        _flash.attr( 'height', "100%" );
        _flash.append( _messageNoFlash );

        $this.html( _flash );
    }
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE needs a `<param name="movie" value="blah.swf">`, you should append this to `_flash`

You could even append the `<embed>` version of it.

See how to structure a multibrowser compatible Flash object here:
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashsatay

Or, easier, you could use SWFObject:
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: I included the param but it didn't work, it still doesn't display it in IE, I am checking the swfobject!

Comment: Thank you, I included the param etc directly in the html, instead of the .js as shown on the sample code I posted, and it now displays it in IE. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed Flash. There's absolutely no reason not to. You don't even have to host the script yourself, Google does it for you: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/hosted_library

Example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {"ID": WEBCAM_QRCODE_ID}; // fill in this value
    var params = {};
    var attributes = {};
    swfobject.embedSWF("path/to/webcamqrcode.swf", "flash", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", null, flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="flash"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```